# How to programmatically get scheme from an installed app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, url-scheme, launching-application

I'm making an app that shows you the list of all apps you have installed, then when I select then, I want to launch that app in my device. I'm using the following code

```
- (IBAction)openapp:(NSString*)app
{
    urlString =  [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@:",app.accessibilityLabel];//init string with app name and append it to ":"

    [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "withString:@""];//remove all spaces

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];//open URL with scheme
}
```

It work in some cases that the scheme is the same as the name of the app, but sometimes it fails because it isn't (example - facebook scheme = fb). So, I need to get the scheme of the app from somewhere. Also I can't just create a NSString and alloc a fixed scheme there because the app I'll be opening will change from device to device.
Anyone can help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible due to the sandbox nature of apps meaning that the required information isn't readable. I can't find reference to any Apple collated list either.

This quote from the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html), though not conclusive, implies that it's not possible since it's not even possible to determine which app, if any, will open.

> **Note: If more than one third-party app registers to handle the same URL scheme, there is currently no process for determining which app will be given that scheme.

---

If you already know which apps you want to check are installed, this method should return YES:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myScheme://"]
```

Comment: Actually, i can already open any app. The problem is that i have to predetermine the scheme to open this apps, for example, for facebook, i would need to create a NSString with @"fb:"to open it, and i don't wanna do this hand job. What i wanna do is to get the scheme that opens certain app from its name. I wanna go from Facebook to fb:. But im almost concluding that is impossible